# keep track of successive repeatnace of a digit in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array with some 0's and 1's.Now I want to find how much time 1 comes successively(the largest value). Like I have an array of 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1.Then my result will be 4. I can count the total occurrence of 1 but can't keep the successive occurrence. How can I keep the result of successive occurance.I am beginner

Comment: Hm. What is he problem, exactly? Reset the counter when seeing a zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you encounter a 0 you need to reset the counter. Before resetting however you need to check if the value is greater than the previous value you had for your counter.

I don't quite remember C syntax 100%, but something like this:

```
int size = sizeof(yourArray) / sizeof(int);
int largest = 0;
int counter = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(yourArray[i] == 1) {
        counter++;
        if(counter > largest) {
            largest = counter;
        }       
    } else {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now you could try a solution without repeating the last *if* ..

Comment: You don't need the last if statement in this code.

Comment: Something is needed for when ending on a 1

Comment: I could remove the last `if` and instead move the `if` in the `else` to be right after else instead. But I don't think that is better since in every iteration there will be an additional `if`to evaluate

Answer (score 0):

This should work I guess

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()
{
    int a[10] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1};

    int count = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == 1)
            temp++;
        else
        {
            if (count < temp)                                                                                                                         
            {
                count = temp;
                temp = 0;
            }
        }

    }
    if (count < temp)
    {
        count = temp;
        temp = 0;
    }
    printf (" Total %d", count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple backtracking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int array[] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1};
    int size, i, maxSoFar = 0, maxEndingHere = 0;

    size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 1) {
            maxEndingHere++;
        } else {
            maxEndingHere = 0;
        }
        if (maxEndingHere > maxSoFar) {
            maxSoFar = maxEndingHere;
        }
    }

    printf("%d", maxSoFar);

    return 0;
}
```